# How to apply order by clause in zendframework 2?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

In Zendframework 1 we use the following code in the models to apply where and order by clauses:

```
$this->select()
     ->where('WHERE CLAUSE')
     ->order('ORDER FIELDS');
```

But in Zendframework 2 it has been changed to:

```
$this->select('WHERE CLAUSE');
```

I dont know how to apply order by clause to my select object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually several ways to achieve where-clauses in ZF2, the most 'nerdy' one being

```
$select = $this->select();

$where = function(Where $clause) {
  $clause->like('username', 'foo%');
};

$select->where($where);
```

As for the orther, it's the same as in ZF1

```
$select->order('id DESC');
```

Read more about the possibilities inside the [Official Documentation of \Zend\Db\Sql](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.db.sql.html#order)